# React - Best way to filter through url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router to display an array of data.

On `/products`, I get a list of all my products. If I use `/products?category=Women`, it filters my items though their category, and if I type `/products?type=shirt`, it will filter according to their type (basically, `/products?[target]=[query]` will filter by target attribute.

Now, I'd like to change my URL accordingly, if my user clicks on the 'Shirt' type button, this shall replace my url to get its `?type=shirt` thing, while still matching any previous query. If my URL already includes a query, I don't want it to be replaced, but rather to sum all the filters so that `/products?type=shirt&category=Women` displays only my shirts for women.

Parsing my URL is a breeze, I'm using query string to do so, but I have no idea how to keep the existing filters when adding a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extend your queries like

```
const query = queryString.parse(location.search);
const modifiedQuery = {
   ...query,
   {[target]: queryVal}
}
history.replace({
   pathname: location.pathname,
   search: queryString.stringify(modifiedQuery)
})
```